# virtual function override intended error

Tags: c++

In C++, I want to convert a class into another class, so I decided to create a template class, but I'm having a compilation error, here is the error,

```
"MyFooClass.h", line 10: error (etoa:4997):
      function "IFoo::show(OtherClass &)" is hidden by
      "MyFooClass::show" -- virtual function override
      intended?
  virtual std::auto_ptr<ClNewClass> show(ClOldClass  &oc)
```

And here is my codes,

```
//IFoo.h
class IFoo
{
    public:
        virtual ~IFoo(){}

    protected:
        virtual std::auto_ptr<OtherClass> show(OtherClass &oc) = 0;
};

//CustomFoo.h
template<typename oldClass, typename newClass>
class CustomFoo : public IFoo
{
    public:
        virtual std::auto_ptr<newClass> show(oldClass &oc)=0;

    protected:
        virtual std::auto_ptr<OtherClass> show(OtherClass &oc)
        {
            std::auto_ptr<OtherClass> result(show(static_cast<oldClass &>(oc)));
            return result;
        }
}; 

//MyFooClass.h
class MyFooClass : public CustomFoo< ClOldClass, ClNewClass >
{
    public:
        virtual std::auto_ptr<ClNewClass> show(ClOldClass &oc)
        {
            std::auto_ptr<ClNewClass> cnv(new ClNewClass(oc.params));
            return cnv;
        }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of that "class conversion"? What is `MyFooClass` actually supposed to do?

Comment: This is an adapter class. I have another class that is using the ClOldClass, but I want to change it to ClNewClass. But I don't want the other class to send a new class, instead it will still use the ClOldClass. But then, my another class, is using the ClNewClass. Like I'm changing inside of my another class.

Comment: `MyFooClass` is ultimately derived from `IFoo`, but it does not override its `show` function correctly. The return type of that function must be `std::auto_ptr<ClOldClass>`, not `std::auto_ptr<ClNewClass>`. You can't change that fact by putting another class into the class hierachy that overrides the correct function as `protected` and introduces a new one as `public`.

Comment: @jogojapan : The return type is not part of a function's signature. The problem is that the argument is different. This is an overload rather than an override. The problem is that the overloaded `show()` hides the `show()` that would otherwise be inherited.

Comment: @DavidHammen I didn't say it's part of the signature. I said that in order to override the function correctly, the return type must match (or be a pointer to a derived class type, to be specific).

Answer (score 0):

The function `show(ClOldClass&)` in class `MyFooClass` is a different function than the function `show(OtherClass&)` in class `CustomFoo`. The new definition hides the other one.

Did you really mean to overload here as opposed to override? If you meant to override, your new function needs to have the same signature as in the parent classes. If really did mean to overload the function, you still need that other `show`. Add a `using CustomFoo::show;` directive to your class `MyFooClass`.

```
//MyFooClass.h
class MyFooClass : public CustomFoo< ClOldClass, ClNewClass >
{
    public:
        virtual std::auto_ptr<ClNewClass> show(ClOldClass &oc) {...}

    protected:
        using CustomFoo::show;
};
```

Comment: *If you meant to overload, your new function should have the same signature. If you meant to override, you still need that other show.* did you mean to say it the other way round? Cause you cannot overload with the same signature, but overriding requires the same signature.